# How get only those object which has name equal to Delhi inside the object as element in Json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-api-nodejs-client

Here i m given some data in Json formate. I want to fillter it with it atrribute .

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "ShalimarBhagh",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "1",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Janpat, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "2",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "MSP, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "3",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "4",
    "name": "MSP, Pune",
    "city_id": "2",
    "location_id": "4",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "5",
    "name": "Anand Pur",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "5",
    "country_name": "India"
},
```

]

From the Above Json file just want to display only those object which has arrtibute with that value  ( name:"Delhi")

it Should be Displayed like that by using node.js and React

```
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Janpat, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "2",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "MSP, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "3",
    "country_name": "India"
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Just use array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    name: "ShalimarBhagh",
    city_id: "1",
    location_id: "1",
    country_name: "India",
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Janpat, Delhi",
    city_id: "1",
    location_id: "2",
    country_name: "India",
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    name: "MSP, Delhi",
    city_id: "1",
    location_id: "3",
    country_name: "India",
  },
];

const filtered = data.filter((item) =>
  item.name.toLowerCase().includes("delhi")
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Hi, @MauroAguilar thank you very much bro it helps me a lot, and I want to practice more with JSON so please refer me best website if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is stored in a variable called `elements`.

What you can do is `filter` all of the elements with a condition that the `name` `includes` string `"Delhi"`

```
const elements = [
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "ShalimarBhagh",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "1",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Janpat, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "2",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "MSP, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "3",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "4",
    "name": "MSP, Pune",
    "city_id": "2",
    "location_id": "4",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "5",
    "name": "Anand Pur",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "5",
    "country_name": "India"
}];

const result = elements.filter(element => element.name.includes("Delhi"));

console.log(result);
```

Now `result` contains all elements whose name includes Delhi. Note that this does not modify the original array, instead it returns a new array.

Comment: Hi, @milansav  thank you very much bro it helps me a lot, and I want to practice more with JSON so please refer me best website if you know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.filter()` function. If the array is named `arr` then:

```js
var new_array = arr.filter(function callback(element, index, array) {
    return (element.name.includes("Delhi"))
});
```

Where `new_array` is the filtered array.

Comment: Hi, @SharjeelAhmed thank you very much bro it helps me a lot, and I want to practice more with JSON so please refer me best website if you know.